# Add extra Axis Ticks and Labels in 3D plots

Tags: plotting

I know how to control FrameTicks in 2D plots, which allows to add them both on left/right and top/bottom edges.  How to do the same with Plot3D ?  How to duplicate the same, say, vertical axis with ticks at several vertical box edges? 
Thank you,
Sergey

Comment: Verbatim from the documentation: `In three dimensions, axes are drawn on the edges of the bounding box specified by the option AxesEdge.`

Answer (score 1):

Place tick marks at specific positions:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
Ticks -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi}, {0, Pi/2, Pi}, {-1, 0, 1}}]
```

Comment: Not sure it answers the question.